# Is there a lowercase expression for .Net regular expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Perl has the \u operator to lowercase a match when using string replacement and regular expressions. Does .Net have anything similar? For example, uppercase all words that start with a <

```
s/<\(\w*\)/<\U\1/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression Uppercase Replacement in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205382/regular-expression-uppercase-replacement-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do these kind of things in .NET is using the MatchEvaluator parameter:

```
string pattern = @"<(\w*)";
string replaced = Regex.Replace(line, pattern, 
                  x => "<" + x.Groups[1].ToString().ToUpper());
```

This reads: Whenever you find the regular expression, replace it with the first group uppercased.

Comment: Would using `Groups[0]` be more appropriate as a general approach? Some regexes do not have a grouping in them.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some errors in your Perl code.  In both Perl and .NET regexes, `\(` and `\)` match the literal characters, `(` and `)`; to use parentheses as grouping operators, leave the backslashes off.  Also, `\u` does not *lowercase a match*, it **titlecases** (usually the same as uppercasing) the next *character*.  What you're thinking of is `\L`, which lowercases all characters until the end of the string or `\E`, whichever comes first.

In Perl, `\U`, `\L` and such aren't really a regex feature, they're a string feature, like the more common escape sequences: `\n`, `\t`, etc..  They're listed redundantly in the regex docs because they're especially useful in regex substitutions.  C# has no equivalent for them, either in string literals or the regex classes, but as @steinar pointed out, it does have MatchEvaluator and (since .NET 3.0) lambda expressions:

```
string s = "ABC<XYZ!";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"<(\w+)", m => m.Value.ToLower()));
```

output:

```
ABC<xyz!
```

**edit:** The parentheses aren't really necessary in my example, but I left them in to demonstrate their proper use as grouping operators.  I also changed the original `\w*` to `\w+`; there's no point matching zero word characters when your only goal is to change the case of word characters.