# RegEx to set title case and then upper case for any word with mixed numbers and letters

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following sample strings:

```
PP12111 LOREM IPSUM TM ENCORE
LOREM PP12111 IPSUM TM ENCORE
LOREM IPSUM ENCORE TM PP12111
LOREM PP12111 PP12111 TM ENCORE
```

What would be a .NET RegEx to set title case and then convert any string containing numbers and letters to upper case (see note below):

```
PP12111 Lorem Ipsum TM Encore
Lorem PP12111 Ipsum TM Encore
Lorem Ipsum Encore TM PP12111
Lorem PP12111 PP12111 TM Encore
```

Alternativley, I can start with everything set to Title Case so only the strings containing numbers and letters need to be set to upper case:

```
Pp12111 Lorem Ipsum TM Encore
Lorem Pp12111 Ipsum TM Encore
Lorem Ipsum Encore TM Pp12111
Lorem Pp12111 Pp12111 TM Encore
```

**Note**: if any variant of TM exists (tm, Tm, tM), the it should be full upper case. Where the TM could be "lorem ipsum TM valor" or "lorem ipsum (TM) valor".

Here is a pure string manipulation method that works; I would think that a RegEx solution may be a better fit?

```
private static void Main( string[] args )
{
    var phrases = new[]
        {
          "PP12111 LOREM IPSUM TM ENCORE", "LOREM PP12111 IPSUM TM ENCORE",
          "LOREM IPSUM ENCORE TM PP12111", "LOREM PP12111 PP12111 TM ENCORE",
        };

    Test(phrases);
}

private static void Test( IList<string> phrases )
{
    var ti = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;

    for( int i = 0; i < phrases.Count; i++ )
    {
        string p = ti.ToTitleCase( phrases[i].ToLower() );
        string[] words = p.Split( ' ' );

        for( int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++ )
        {
            string word = words[j];
            if( word.ToCharArray().Any( Char.IsNumber ) )
            {
                word = word.ToUpper();
            }
            words[j] = word.Replace( " Tm ", " TM " ).Replace( "(Tm)", "(TM)" );
        }

        phrases[i] = string.Join( " ", words );

        Console.WriteLine( phrases[i] );
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to do it with regex alone. You still need a callback function to take care of changing the case. Have a look at [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) of `Regex.Replace`.

Comment: @m.buettner - Thanks for the link; I'll review and hopefully it will provide me a better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex like this:

```
MatchEvaluator evaluator = m => ti.ToTitleCase(m.Value.ToLower());
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b(?!TM\b)[A-Z']+\b", evaluator,
                              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

`\b`                       Is a word boundary.
`pos(?!suffix)` Matches position not preceeding suffix.
`\b(?!TM\b)`       Word boundary not preceeding TM
`[A-Z]+`               Words without digits.

Together: Word boundary not preceeding "TM" followed by words with letters A through Z and word boundary.

---

**UPDATE #1**

*Upper casing "tm", "Tm", "tM":*

I don't know if everything not capitalized can be upper case. In that case the easiest solution would be to upper case the input: `input.ToUpper()`. Otherwise execute  a second regex replace:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\btm\b", "TM", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

If you want to upper case several words, you can just use another match evaluator:

```
MatchEvaluator toUpperCase = m => m.Value.ToUpper();
string result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\b(tm|xxx|yyy)\b", toUpperCase,
                              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

`tm|xxx|yyy` specifies the words to be upper cased ("tm", "xxx" or "yyy").

Comment: An impressive effort, but will fail to format on variants of "TM": "LOREM IPSUM ENCORE tm PP12111", "LOREM IPSUM ENCORE tM PP12111", etc. I suppose you could change Regex.Replace(input [...]) with Regex.Replace(input.ToUpper [...]) . It seems like you'd be fruitlessly switching cases on a lot of words just to catch the exception then. Maybe a 2nd just for "TM"? But that's equally inelegant.

Comment: Fantastic! Much cleaner than my string manipulation and works great. I've ran this through our catalog of some 7000 items and a cursory scan looks like everything is formatted as expected. A question on the Update: there may be other one-off words that have to be replaced; can you string several of the Regex.Replaces together?

Comment: Looks like there is an edge case with contractions: i.e., `CONTRACTIONS DON'T TITLE CASE CORRECTLY` becomes `Contractions Don'T Title Case Correctly`

Comment: I just added a `'` to `[A-Z']+` to take account of cases like `don't` and added an update to expand upper-casing to more words.

Comment: Makes sense. Appreciate the effort and the RegEx is even readable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a previously asked close match for you to review: [Regular Expression Uppercase Replacement in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205382/regular-expression-uppercase-replacement-in-c-sharp). A regular expression won't be enough here, you'll have to write a MatchEvaluator function to get everything into uppercase.

edit: Seeing "Note: if any variant of TM exists (tm, Tm, tM), the it should be full upper case. Where the TM could be "lorem ipsum TM valor" or "lorem ipsum (TM) valor"." makes me think you should stop considering a regex altogether. What about ex. oa***tm***eal, stun***tm***en or etc, etc, etc.

Yes, you probably can write one regex that will find all of the cases, or a good and thorough matchevaluator that will take your logic into account. However, you're describing the problem in terms that make me think you're unfamiliar with regular expressions. So it's hard for me to think this is a good answer for you and would be a "stunty" solution rather than anything that should go into production.

Comment: Clearly I'm not familiar with RegEx :). Olivier's answer has done a good job of laying things out nicely. The concerns over oatmeal, et. al. are noted. However, the TM will always be a separate word or within parenthesis.

Comment: Oliver's answer is superlative and I'm glad to see you accepted it :) If you're interested in digging into regular expressions, please check out the gold standard book, _Mastering Regular Expressions_ http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do

Answer (score -1):

First: LowerCase Everything.

Second: Split sentence into words.

For each word:

Check, if there are just two letters or letters and numbers `([a-z]{2}|[a-z0-9]{2,})`

Match -> UpperCase it.

No Match-> TitleCase it.

Comment: What's the purpose of changing the case twice? The initial casing has no bearing on whether or not the final result is upper or title cased.

Comment: you'r right - but then dont forget to extend the MatchGroups or make the regex case insensitive.

Comment: There's a prolem with this idea. With the proposed rules, of, we, and us would all get converted to upper case.